# Parent class is not inherited by the descendant element in the child component-using scss

Tags: angular, sass

I have a parent component whose class is set through a directive (I gives me a theme based on the user input).

In the child component's `SCSS` style even the simplest rules that refer to the parent class do not work. I read about the shadow-piercing and set the `ViewEncapsulation` to `None` in the parent component but couldn't get it to work as I'm sure there is something missing that I don't know about.

**app.component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div appTheme> <---- This one generates: class="theme-snow-cherry" (for example)
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**ribbon.component.scss** (child component)

```
.theme-snow-cherry div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[image]

**Note:** If I add the aforementioned style in my `app.component.css` it will give me the result, but obviously it is not where I want to put the style.

Comment: Any chance you can inspect the element in your browser's debugger and show what the actual rendered dom looks like?

Comment: @Pace Actually I don't understand what you mean exactly, as I have already shown the rendered dom. I just add some more details into my question.

Comment: You're right, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you define the style in the child component, you should set the encapsulation to `ViewEncapsulation.None` in that component:

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class RibbonComponent {
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, the generated class style has an attribute specific to the child component, which prevents the selector `.theme-snow-cherry` from matching the div element in the parent component:

```
.theme-snow-cherry[_ngcontent-c2] div[_ngcontent-c2] {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works; although I feel a bit that I am losing some control over my child component's styles. Anyway I just solved it with this selector: `.theme-snow-cherry app-ribbon div`.

Comment: There may be other ways to style the child component, but I wanted to explain why your original code didn't work as you expected. I also took into account the fact that you want to define the style in the child component and set the class in the parent.

Comment: Yes, and your answer perfectly works. I just want to know is there any other way that regarding these details will serve the purpose without giving up the encapsulation; though it seems to be tolerable.